Stick container till children are scrolled to the end
I've a position: sticky; top: 80px style on the cards, and there's a heading above the card, that explains what those cards are for, and I want the heading to show up till all the sticky cards are scrolled to the end. That means I don't want the heading for the cards to scroll up before all cards are scrolled and viewed.
Code Pen Demo
I set position: sticky to the cards-list which renders both the heading and the cards, but that won't allow the cards to be scrolled, as we've nested position: sticky
Code snippet:


body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: orange;
  position: sticky;
  top: 80px;
}
<div class="header">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="cards-list">
  <p>Your security prioritized</p>
  <p>
    Have peace of mind knowing your data is safe and not being fed into open AI models. Our
    proprietary technology is secured and optimized for you.
  </p>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Multi-Factor Authentication</p>
    <p>
      We employ email validation after registration as well as MFA for all login attempts to protect
      user accounts.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Absolute Privacy Assurance</p>
    <p>
      Only you and your designated team members have direct access to your data, maintaining strict
      confidentiality.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Protected Script Storage</p>
    <p>
      We train our models via coveted, curated, and current data partnerships–your data stays
      protected and private to you.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>






body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: orange;
  position: sticky;
  top: 80px;
}

.cards-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}
<div class="header">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="cards-list">
  <div class="cards-header">
  <p>Your security prioritized</p>
  <p>
    Have peace of mind knowing your data is safe and not being fed into open AI models. Our
    proprietary technology is secured and optimized for you.
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Multi-Factor Authentication</p>
    <p>
      We employ email validation after registration as well as MFA for all login attempts to protect
      user accounts.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Absolute Privacy Assurance</p>
    <p>
      Only you and your designated team members have direct access to your data, maintaining strict
      confidentiality.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Protected Script Storage</p>
    <p>
      We train our models via coveted, curated, and current data partnerships–your data stays
      protected and private to you.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
    id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>



